# MtGox Daily Withdrawal Limit

Tags: mtgox

Simple question about Mt Gox's terms for "unverified" "level 0" accounts:
See this URL: https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20919111-AML-Account-Statuses

It says that the daily limit for USD "or equivalent" is 1000USD.
And daily limit for bitcoin is 100BTC.

So my question: if current exchange rate is 100USD/BTC, I can withdraw 100BTC from MtGox to my personal wallet in one day, and then exchange the 100BTC in my wallet for 10,000USD at another exchange, potentially, assuming that another exchaneg will offer me 100USD/BTC?

On other words, is the daily limit of 1000USD only for withdrawing directly to USD?  Or does it mean that the equivalent of 1000USD (10BTC) is the limit no matter whether I'm withdrawing USD or coins?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to deal with whatever AML rules the other exchange has.

Comment: OK, but I can always withdraw up to 100BTC per day from mtGOX to any bitcoin address, and then the receiving party deals with AML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USD limit is only for funds being removed as USD.  They do not value BTC in USD to see if it crosses the limit.